# "Delete" command in suggested edits queue gives strange error non-message

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, moderator-tools, tag-wiki

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to an SE site where you have moderator privileges.
2. Have a user with rep sufficiently low as to require that tag wiki edits be reviewed edit the tag wiki for some tag, e.g. [foo](/questions/tagged/foo).
3. Go to the suggested edits queue and press "Delete".

#### Result:

This shows up:

[image: blank modal dialog]

Followed by this:

[image: non-modal error box]

#### Expected result:

The modal dialog that pops up first should either 1.) have something in it; or 2.) not pop up at all.

Furthermore, if it's categorically impossible to delete tag wikis from the suggested edits queue, the "Delete" button shouldn't even show up for those in the first place.